# Add a remote printer over ssh on OSX?

Tags: macos, ssh, printer, cups

I have a printer at my office that is connected to a local network and my linux box at work can see it on the network. However, it is not visible to the outside world.

I was trying to figure out a way to add it on my MacAir and so far have found two options:

1) Using ssh tunnel via CLI: cat file.pdf | ssh user@linuxbox lpr. 
2) With Chrome installed on the linux box, using the Google Cloud Print service on the remote box and automator on my MacAir I can add the printer to `Cmnd+p` dialog box

I like the first method since it does not require Chrome be installed and the second one since it allows to use `Cmnd+p` inside all applications. I was wondering if there is a way to combine by using automator to run the first command line script.

What about port forwarding? Is it possible to forward the remote CUPS `631` port to a local port and then add the printer normally? What other methods would you recommend?

Comment: Are these two descriptions  *(1) 'my office'* and *(2) 'at work'* describing *(a) one and the same place*  or  *(b) two different locations*? -- Is your MacAir trying to access the printer from the network describing *'(1)'* or the network describing *'(2)'* or the location describing *'(3) the outside world'*?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle My bad. Work and Office  are the same place, i.e. linux box is connected to same network as the printer. My MacAir, however, is on a separate network (say home) which is "outside world" to the local network at the office.

Answer (score 0):

3) Install [cloudprint](https://github.com/armooo/cloudprint/) on the Linux machine.